# Run function on a specific UTC +5:30 Time once

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function main().
I want to run this function at times 9:25,1:25,5:25 (considering 12 hour clock time-means 9:30 in the morning as well as at the night).
As the clock hits any of the times mentioned above, the function should run once. Then the function should wait for next time.
Like function runs at 9:30 in the morning (but only once and then stops) then it should wait for 1:25 in the afternoon. I want all this to be coded in Javascript. Is there any scheduler which will help me...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```js
var times = [[9, 25], [1, 25], [5, 25]];
var lastrun;

function checktime(){
    now = new Date(); // Get the current time
    if (lastrun != null){
        if (now-lastrun > 60000) return; // Wait until a minute has elapsed
        // (In order to avoid the function running twice within the same minute)
    }
    ok = false;
    for (time of times){ // Iterate through target times
        target = new Date(); // Create a new date where the target time will be held
        target.setHours(time[0]); // Set the hour and minute to the target time
        target.setMinutes(time[1]);
        if (now.getTime() >= target.getTime()){ // Check if the target time has been reached
            ok = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ok){
        lastrun = now; // Store the time when the function was last run
        main(); // Run the main function if 'ok' is true
    }
}

setInterval(checktime, 1000);
```

Comment: But what If i deploy it on heroku with timezone UTC and 24 hrs clock

Comment: @62_Syedfardin To test for both AM/PM, just extend the times array to contain versions of each time with the hour increased by 12. For other time zones, offset the target times by the time difference of your timezone and Heroku's, if that makes sense.